# Bash: How to use while shift; do..case $1 in

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script and i need to implement "options".
How can i do that with bash?

my goal is tu run script the following way:
`/myscript.sh -d "/var/log/" -c "test"`

what i've tried:

```
while shift; do
        case $1 in
                -d)
                        shift&&DIR="$1"||die
                ;;
                -c)
                        shift&&COMMAND="$1"||die
                ;;
        esac
done

echo "$DIR"
echo "$COMMAND"
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when you try this?

Comment: print only the -c) case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand @choroba's answer, here's an example of how to use `getopts`:

```
# parse the flag options (and their arguments)
while getopts c:d: OPT; do
    case "$OPT" in
      d)
        DIR="$OPTARG" ;;
      c)
        COMMAND="$OPTARG" ;;
      [?])
        # got invalid option
        echo "Usage: $0 [-d directory] [-c command]" >&2
        exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

# get rid of the just-finished flag arguments
shift $(($OPTIND-1))
```

Note that after shifting off the flag arguments, any "regular" arguments will remain. So at that point you could either deal with them (e.g. `... for arg in "$@"; do ...`) or if your script doesn't take them just gripe if you get any (`if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then echo "Usage ...`).

Comment: getopt is an external dependency.  The original author only asked about shift, not getopt.

Comment: @heroxbd `getopt` is an external command, but I'm suggesting `getopts` (note the "s"), which is a shell builtin.

Comment: Using `getopt` is a bad idea for several reasons. For more informations and good practices on processing arguments using `bash`, read [BashFAQ/035: How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Answer (score 12):

Your mistake is that you're shifting at the top of the loop, tossing the first argument before you've examined it.  This is what I think you probably meant:

```
#!/bin/bash
while (( "$#" )); do
   case $1 in
      -d)
         shift&&DIR="$1"||die
         ;;
      -c)
         shift&&COMMAND="$1"||die
         ;;
   esac
   shift
done

echo "$DIR"
echo "$COMMAND"
```

Comment: die? bash is not Perl

Comment: @glennjackman Good comment. I didn't catch that as a possible problem.  (Note the OP explains that the complaint is that it only prints the -c) case.)  I assumed `die` was probably an alias -- or at least, that whatever it was didn't matter to the question.

Comment: right, I commented to the wrong person...

Answer (score 2):

As choroba already said, [getopts](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?getopts+1) is a better approach.

In your case, you could use:

```
getopts c:d: d || die
DIR=$OPTARG
getopts c:d: c || die
COMMAND=$OPTARG
```

to achieve what you're trying to do with the while loop.

The string `c:d:` specifies the possible switches. The colon means that the switch requires an argument.

The problem with your approach is that you call `shift` before analyzing the first argument, discarding it in the process.

To fix this, change the while loop to the following:

```
while true; do
        case $1 in
                -d)
                        shift&&DIR="$1"||die
                ;;
                -c)
                        shift&&COMMAND="$1"||die
                ;;
        esac
        shift || break
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use `getopts`.